# The number of dominating sets of a bipartite graph is not exactly divisible by $2$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

here is a cute problem I created from another cute problem. Prove the number of dominating sets of a bipartite graph is never exactly divisible by $2$.

A dominating set of a graph is a set of vertices $D$ such that every vertex not in $D$ is adjacent to at least one vertex in $D$

Regards.

Comment: i'm not quite sure yet but it seems to me that mapping each dominating set to the set of vertices that are neighbors of at least one element of the dominating set gives us a bijection between dominating sets. it would have to be shown though that this really is a bijection and that only the set that contains all the vertices is mapped to itself.

Comment: What about $K_2$ ?  It's bipartite, and has 2 dominating sets.  Or, do you count $V$ as a dominating set ?

Comment: @manuellafond I think $V(G)$ is a dominating set by default based on the definition given.

Comment: Yes, $V$ is a dominating set, it satisfies the condition vacuosly.

Comment: Of course :)  That's a fun problem indeed.  So, have you solved it and posted to share, or are you also looking for an answer ?

Comment: I have a solution, but I would like to see if there are other solutions.I'll post my solution in some time if no one writes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually true for all graphs $G$, and can be proven by considering the Domination Polynomial of a graph; $D(G,x) := \sum_{k=0}^{|V(G)|} d_k(G) x^k$
where $d_k(G)$ is the number of dominating sets of cardinality $k$ in $G$.

Your problem is thus to show that $D(G,1) \equiv 1 \mod 2$.
We proved it as a corollary to another result in [Subset-Sum Representations of Domination Polynomials.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.2430) (Graphs Combin. 30 (2014), no. 3, 647–660.)

It can also be shown by induction using this recurrence from [Recurrence relations and splitting formulas for the domination polynomial](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5926): (Electron. J. Combin. 19 (2012), no. 3, Paper 47)

$$D(G, x) = xD(G/u, x) + D(G − u, x) + xD(G − N[u], x) − (1 + x)p_u(G, x)$$

When we substitute $x=1$ into this you can see that the last term is even and thus there are 3 terms belonging to smaller graphs which are necessarily odd by the induction hypothesis; 3 odd numbers added makes an odd number.

The first proofs we found of this result were published by Andries E. Brouwer: [The number of dominating sets of a ﬁnite graph is odd.](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/preprints/domin2.pdf)